# Java Finding a certain digit in a string array

Tags: java

I am currently working on an assignment.  What I need to do is take in a file that the user presents, so it will be this one [here](http://www.writeurl.com/text/ew40igzvms0lvavaf6h1/7mwg41itnrkgyqy37gy8/lbda0mglln5bjue1pdzr), and from there it will take in a number, the popularity, to look for and after that it will take in the decade through which to look.  What I need to do is find within the lines the popularity of said name corresponding to the selected decade.

My code is this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FiletoArray {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input file : ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();
    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

    System.out.print("What rank of popularity? ");
    int getPop = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter number correpsonding to your decade: ");
    System.out.println("   1 - 1900-1909");
    System.out.println("   2 - 1910-1919");
    System.out.println("   3 - 1920-1929");
    System.out.println("   4 - 1930-1939");
    System.out.println("   5 - 1940-1949");
    System.out.println("   6 - 1950-1959");
    System.out.println("   7 - 1960-1969");
    System.out.println("   8 - 1970-1979");
    System.out.println("   9 - 1980-1989");
    System.out.println("   10 - 1990-1999");
    System.out.println("   11 - 2000-2005");
    System.out.print("Decade: ");
    int getDecade = console.nextInt();



    String[] namesArray = new String[4429];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4429; i++)
    {
        namesArray[i] = in.nextLine();
    }

    int searchedValue = (int) getDecade+1;
    int pos = 0;
    int newPos = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (pos < namesArray.length && !found)
    {
        if(namesArray[pos].equals(getPop))
        {
            found = true;
            newPos = pos;
            System.out.println(namesArray[pos]);
        }
        else
        {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    if (found == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Found at position: " + newPos);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found.");
    }
}
}
```

For the time being, I just want it to print out the line so I know I got it.  Thanks a lot for the help!

EDIT:
The result I am expecting is for the individual to type in:

```
Input file: names.txt

What rank of popularity? 380

What decade? 10
```

Then the resultant should pop out something like:

`Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215`

Unfortunately, it just keeps defaulting to:
`Not found.`

Comment: can you please give a use case/example of what the user will enter and result to be expected ?

Comment: Did so, thanks a lot and sorry about forgetting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is unavailable, but based on your example, it's probably failing here:

```
if(namesArray[pos].equals(getPop))
```

You should print out what is really in `namesArray[pos]`. From your sample output, you are looking for this to print out `Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215`. Well, that will never be equal to `getPop`, what you are searching for, which again, from your example is `380`.

So, you should see that this will never be true:

```
"Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215".equals(380) // ALWAYS false
```

Instead, you will need to parse the `namesArray[pos]` string (either when you read the file, or in the loop, look at [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))), pull out the value `380`, and compare against that.

You could also do [`String#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) if its sufficient to just test for the line to contain `380`. Instead of:

```
if(namesArray[pos].equals(getPop))
```

Do:

```
if(namesArray[pos].contains(getPop))
```

However, it's possible this approach will produce false positives.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare the *entire line* of text from the file (e.g. `Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215`) to the *number* the user entered as popularity. You need to parse each `namesArray` element to get the values by decade, then only compare the relevant value against `getPop`.

Hint: you'll use your `getDecade` value to select the "relevant" value.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much!